# The Android Studio show me this error message and making me feel so confused

Tags: java, android, project

Here was an issue happen on the Android Studio. I using the MacBook Pro 14-inch and using the USB to save my Android Project. However, for unknown reason, here was my project print this error message when I try to run it: '/Volumes/HOMEWORK/Java_Application_For_FIT2081/app/build/intermediates/packaged_res/debug/._drawable' is not a directory. I try to clean and rebuild the Project buy still not solve this issue, even I restarted the Android Studio or Eject my USB and plug in back. Please someone help me out. Thanks you.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem. Any reason you don't use version control and make regular backups?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it shows this error. if you involve in this error you can restart your phone and then continue your work. I hope you will get your solution